# Visual Studio Code server (vscode-server) keeps disconnecting and disposing off my connection ["Disposed of connection to running server."]

Tags: visual-studio-code, remote-server, vscode-remote, vscode-server, remote-tunnel

I am using VS code on my local machine to connect through "remote tunnel" to a GCP machine which is running the VS Code server.

Recently, I have started to get this weird behaviour where VS Code server disposes off my connection after some time.

Consequently, I keep losing part of my work and I have to restart the whole process.

This is so annoying and I was wondering if someone can help me fix this.

Following is the error message from the code server when it disposes of my connection.

```
(conda)jupyter@splintered-learning:~$ code-server

(conda)jupyter@splintered-learning:~$ code-server

Open this link in your browser https://insiders.vscode.dev/+ms-vscode.remote-server/**********

[2023-03-14 22:49:08] info [rpc.0] [call.0] Checking /home/jupyter/.vscode-cli/server-stable/.5e805b79fcb6ba4c2d23712967df89a089da575b.log and /home/jupyter/.vscode-cli/server-stable/.5e805b79fcb6ba4c2d23712967df89a089da575b.pid for a running server...
[2023-03-14 22:49:08] info [rpc.0] [call.0] Downloading VS Code server https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/stable/5e805b79fcb6ba4c2d23712967df89a089da575b/vscode-server-linux-x64.tar.gz -> /home/jupyter/.vscode-cli/server-stable/bin/5e805b79fcb6ba4c2d23712967df89a089da575b
[2023-03-14 22:49:09] info [rpc.0] [call.0] Setting up server...
[2023-03-14 22:49:11] info [rpc.0] [call.0] Starting server...
[2023-03-14 22:49:11] info [rpc.0] [call.0] Server started
[2023-03-14 22:49:35] info [rpc.0] Forwarding port 8050
[2023-03-14 22:49:35] info [rpc.0] Forwarding port 8052
[2023-03-14 23:49:09] info [rpc.0] Disposed of connection to running server.
```

Comment: Possibly related issue tickets from the past year: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/170042, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168735. Others that don't mention "forwarding port": https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/167631, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/7943

Comment: @user these are similar issues but not exactly the same. Plus there is no solution suggested :-)

Comment: Have you figured it out? It would be nice if you could post a solution. I'm faced with the same exact issue.

Comment: I am still looking for an answer. It is getting worse day by day. Now it keeps dropping in middle of my work suggesting different errors.